# How to generate Azure function name based on the publish profile settings?

Tags: c#, azure, deployment, azure-functions

I have created `HttpTrigger` function, which generated code as below in Visual Studio

```
  [FunctionName("Function1")]
  public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
    }
```

if you notice, the name of the function is `Function1`

Now, I have created the following publishing profiles, which deploys function on different `Azure subscriptions`.

1. dev-env-function1-profile
2. test-env-function1-profile
3. production-function1-profile

The issue is, it creates function name as `Function1` in all the subscription, whereas we want have function name as follow for different environments.

1. Dev environment:    devenv-function1
2. Test environment:    testenv-function1
3. Production environment:    function1

How can we set the function name dynamically?

```
    [FunctionName("Function1")] <-- ???
```

Comment: I'm curious why you would rename functions across environments?

Comment: to identify easily in azure portal, just by looking at the name. nothing else. let me know the best practices.

Comment: Surely the name of the app service is enough?

Comment: Yes, I can have different app service names.  Great catch. post it as answer, so that we can close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the answer provided by David.

> Just use different names for the app in dev/test/production environment.